# openSUSE 13.2 kernel upgrade to stable version (4.1)

Tags: linux, kernel, opensuse, linux-kernel, opensuse-13.2

I have openSUSE 13.2, and I try to upgrade the kernel to the last stable version.

I added `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Kernel:/stable/standard/`   to repository and try to upgrade with `sudo zypper dup -r kernel_stable` command.
I get the this error:

```
Checking for file ......................................[done]
(1/3) Installing: kernel-devel-4.1.4-1.1.ga37e14f ..............................................................................[done]
(2/3) Installing: kernel-desktop-4.1.4-1.1.ga37e14f ............................................................................[done]
Additional rpm output:
Creating initrd: /boot/initrd-4.1.4-1.ga37e14f-desktop
Executing: /usr/bin/dracut --logfile /var/log/YaST2/mkinitrd.log --force /boot/initrd-4.1.4-1.ga37e14f-desktop 4.1.4-1.ga37e14f-desktop
*** Including module: bash ***
*** Including module: warpclock ***
*** Including module: i18n ***
*** Including module: network ***
Failed to install module ipv6
Failed to install module xennet
*** Including module: ifcfg ***
*** Including module: drm ***
*** Including module: plymouth ***
*** Including module: kernel-modules ***
Failed to install module sd_mod
Failed to install module hid_generic
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors came from `dracut`, the initramfs infrastructure used in OpenSUSE and RHEL. Some modules can't be installed into the initramfs because they're already available in the kernel.

You can confirm this by inspecting the kernel's config file (i.e. `/boot/config-4.1.4-1.ga37e14f-desktop` file) using any plain text editor. Drivers that are built into the kernel have a value of `y`. In the case of `ipv6`, for example, you should see something along the lines of `CONFIG_IPV6=y`. The same principle applies to all the other modules that `dracut` failed to install to the initramfs.

In conclusion, the installation went fine; try to boot with the new kernel.